# How to avoid deprecation messages from RubyGems?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

After `gem update --system`, when I do something related to rubygems, I receive this message:

> NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
>
> Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications/rubygems-update-1.7.2.gemspec:11.

How can I avoid it? I've tried to remove rubygems and reinstall, but that didn't fix it.

Comment: I so regret updating, what a waste of time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You probably need to regenerate your gem specifications.

> After installing RubyGems 1.8.1 you will see deprecations when loading your exsting gems. Run gem pristine --all --no-extensions to regenerate your gem specifications safely.

http://blog.segment7.net/2011/05/05/rubygems-1-8-1

Comment: Gems with native code will have to be uninstalled then reinstalled.

Comment: When I run this, I get: Restoring gems to pristine condition...
Restored minitest-1.6.0
Restored minitest-1.6.0
Restored rake-0.8.7
Restored rake-0.8.7
RDoc 2.5 did not save method parameters, so you should upgrade your rdoc-data
gem to a version >= 2.5.3.

and then it quits. probably going to look stupid in a comment though. Not sure what to do.

Comment: My gems are vendored by Bundler, so running `gem pristine --all --no-extensions` only restores the bundler gem since that's the only one installed as a system gem. The rest live in my vendor/ruby directory. Anyone know how to make them "pristine" or if there's an argument I can pass into bundler to do this for me? I'd really like to get rid of the flood of deprecation notices.

I'm using Bundler 1.0.15 and RubyGems 1.8.5.

Comment: If `gem pristine` doesn't work for you, try `gem update --system 1.6.2`

Answer (score 5):

Look where your rubygems are installed:

```
$ gem list -d rubygems
```

Find the `deprecate.rb` file there, and make the `self.skip` class method always return true.

or If you're using RVM, the following command will fix it:

```
rvm rubygems current
```

Comment: The RVM fix just downgrades the version of RubyGems.

Comment: For me i have several deprecate.rb files in the same area, i have to do that technique to all of them? Doing it to just one of the files didn't fix my issue of still getting one message after rolling back to 1.7.2.

Comment: It seems I, like many, had problems using 'rvm rubygems current' - error:
Cannot switch to 1.3.7 for this interpreter.
Seems that at some point rvm got messed up (maybe by not using rvm to update rubygems). Found this is easily fixed by this re-installing rvm (no need to uninstall):
$ bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)

Answer (score 4):

Regenerating gem specifications worked for me:
`sudo gem pristine --all --no-extensions`

See:
https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/master/History.txt

You can also downgrade your version of rubygems:
`sudo gem update --system 1.7.1`