# How do I fix Rubygems recent deprecation warning?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, suppress-warnings

I have recently run updates:

```
gem update --system
gem update
```

Now, I come with a lot of deprecation warnings each time I load a gem. For example, `rails console`:

```
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/specifications/rake-0.8.7.gemspec:10.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/specifications/rake-0.8.7.gemspec:10.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2p180@global/specifications/rake-0.8.7.gemspec:10.
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.7)
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > exit
```

I use RVM, Ruby 1.9.2 and Rubygems 1.8.1. Any way to get around this problem? Revert to an older version of rubygems?

Comment: You need to provide more information, what does your Gemfile look like?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid deprecation messages from RubyGems?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909108/how-to-avoid-deprecation-messages-from-rubygems)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I had to downgrade to 1.6.2. Those notices are absolutely ridiculous. They make the latest version completely unusable. There should really be a way to disable them, but until then:

`sudo gem update --system 1.6.2`

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work me. Using a mac, rvm (1.92) and Snow Leopard.

Comment: @mr-walinzi I'm not sure to be honest. I just want to develop my rails app in peace, and i can do that with 1.6.2

Comment: [EDIT] i've upgraded back to 1.8.4 now. The `gem pristine ...` solution seems to work well

Comment: Rolling back is always going to introduce it's own problems - for me, this command doesn't work anyway - on ruby 1.9.1 rubygems.rb:483:in `find_files': undefined method `map' for Gem::Specification:Class (NoMethodError)

Comment: I have tried to run mentioned command but it won't work. Showing below error message.

Fetching rubygems-update-1.6.2.gem
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /usr/bin directory

Answer (score 19):

see here http://ryenus.tumblr.com/post/5450167670/eliminate-rubygems-deprecation-warnings

for short, run

```
gem pristine --all --no-extensions

ruby -e "`gem -v 2>&1 | grep called | sed -r -e 's#^.*specifications/##' -e 's/-[0-9].*$//'`.split.each {|x| `gem pristine #{x} -- --build-arg`}"
```

if the backtick (or backquote) doesn't work for you, as @jari-jokinen has pointed out (thank you!) in some cases, replace the second line with this

```
ruby -e "%x(gem -v 2>&1 | grep called | sed -r -e 's#^.*specifications/##' -e 's/-[0-9].*$//').split.each {|x| %x(gem pristine #{x} -- --build-arg)}"
```

**Note:** If your using Bundler in a production environment your offending gems will have been cached to shared/bundle so you'll need to run these commands using bundle exec

Comment: the first command worked great, but the second is giving me a syntax error (Ruby 1.8.7-p249).  Anyone else?

Comment: I had a syntax error on the second line also so I just did it by hand. Check the output of `gem -v 2>&1 | grep called` and for each of the gems returned by that command, do `gem pristine GEM_NAME_HERE -- --build-arg`. You might need to use `sudo` also.

Comment: hmmm, @aidan-feldman, @mirthlab, may I ask what kind of syntax error was that? I don't think there's any ruby 1.9 only feature used on the second line, possibly missing sed or sudo?

Comment: Backticks didn't work with Ruby Enterprise Edition 2011.03 (1.8.7) and/or Bash 4.1.5(1) so I just replaced them with %x[] like this: `ruby -e "%x[gem -v 2>&1 | grep called | sed -r -e 's#^.*specifications/##' -e 's/-[0-9].*$//'].split.each {|x| %x[gem pristine #{x} -- --build-arg]}"`

Comment: OSX/BSD systems will get a `sed: illegal option -- r` because sed uses different flags. Instead replace `-r` with `-E`, ie: `ruby -e "%x[gem -v 2>&1 | grep called | sed -E -e 's#^.*specifications/##' -e 's/-[0-9].*$//'].split.each {|x| %x[gem pristine #{x} -- --build-arg]}"`

Answer (score 8):

You can also use the more RVM specific `rvm rubygems current` to get back to a safer version of gem (1.6.2 right now).

Comment: Thanks! -> in my case I was using rvm with ruby-1.8.7-p302, running current still gave me rubygems 1.8.6 with all of its warnings; `rvm install rubygems 1.6.2` did the trick.

Answer (score 5):

I took other peoples' answers and scriptified them into something a little more worky for me.  I still had to delete a couple by hand out of /usr/local/cellar.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#

brew install gnu-sed
sudo gem pristine --all --no-extensions
gems=$(gem -v 2>&1 | grep called | gsed -r -e 's#^.*specifications/##' -e 's/-[0-9].*$//')

for gem in $gems
do
  echo Fixing $gem...
  sudo gem pristine $gem -- -build-arg
done
```

Comment: it takes a Scala guy to fix the Ruby gems properly!

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm that 1.8.10 has removed these deprecation warnings in a Rails 3.1 environment as well.

Simply run

```
gem update --system
```

Answer (score 3):

Installing rubygems version 1.8.4 gets rid of the gem spec deprecation warnings:

$ gem update --system

=== 1.8.4 / 2011-05-25

- 1 minor enhancement:

  - Removed default_executable deprecations from Specification.

Answer (score 1):

Run this command 
**sudo gem pristine --all --no-extensions**

to remove all those warning messages.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler:  Add the following to `environment.rb`

```
ActiveSupport::Deprecation.silenced = true
```

Answer (score 1):

### Preferred solution

Use this, a courtesy of [gmarik's gist](https://gist.github.com/gmarik/1382974):

`.bashrc:`

```
if [ -d "$HOME/.ruby/lib/" ]; then
  RUBYLIB="$RUBYLIB:$HOME/.ruby/lib"
  RUBYOPT="-rno_deprecation_warnings_kthxbye"
  export RUBYLIB RUBYOPT
fi
```

`~/.ruby/lib/no_deprecation_warnings_kthxbye.rb`

```
begin
require 'rubygems'
Gem::Deprecate.skip = true if defined?(Gem::Deprecate)
rescue LoadError => e
  p e
end
```

### Fall-back solution

Use it when:

- you use RVM and keep gems in ~
- you can't use `$RUBYLIB` because your IDE ignores it when running unit tests
- you can't upgrade to the latest Rubygems because of some old, unmaintained gems in Gemfile

Modify `rubygems/deprecate.rb`:

```
def self.skip # :nodoc:
  @skip ||= true
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the above options but nothing worked.

Finally, I uninstalled Ruby and all dependencies, installed RVM using the link https://rvm.io/rvm/install,
and reinstalled Ruby using `rvm install ruby`.

Things started working fine!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're ok, It is just a warning where *rake-0.8.7.gemspec* will not meet new standard of RubyGems.

I'm sure rake's creator will get this sync.

Comment: It's not just Rake. It affects a lot of other gems requiring them to be reinstalled if they use native code.

Answer (score 0):

Found that it was coming from `Gem::Version.correct?(nil)` so grep for that

Answer (score -1):

SlimGems might be a solution as well.