# Still getting deprecation warnings in Rails3.1

Tags: testing, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I keep getting depreciation warnings while testing in Rails 3.1 like

```
    RailsProject$ bundle exec autotest
    NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
    Gem.source_index called from /Users/CS/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/ZenTest-4.5.0/lib/autotest.rb:226.
    NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#gems is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
    Gem::SourceIndex#gems called from /Users/CS/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/ZenTest-4.5.0/lib/autotest.rb:226.
    loading autotest/rails
    /Users/CS/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby -I.:lib:test -rubygems -e "%w[test/unit test/unit/rim_test.rb test/unit/page_test.rb test/functional/pages_controller_test.rb test/unit/helpers/pages_helper_test.rb test/unit/order_test.rb test/unit/admin_user_test.rb test/unit/helpers/cart_helper_test.rb test/unit/customer_test.rb test/unit/ordered_service_test.rb test/unit/services_test.rb test/functional/cart_controller_test.rb].each { |f| require f }" | unit_diff -u
    /Users/CS/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb:43: warning: method redefined; discarding old gem_dir
    /Users/CS/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1262: warning: previous definition of gem_dir was here
    /Users/CS/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb:154: warning: method redefined; discarding old hash
    /Users/CS/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/platform.rb:125: warning: previous definition of hash was here
    /Users/CS/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:183: warning: method redefined; discarding old initialize
    /Users/CS/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/deprecate.rb:53: warning: previous definition of initialize was here
```

My versions:

```
    RailsProject$ bundle exec rails -v
    Rails 3.1.0
    RailsProject$ bundle exec gem -v
    1.8.10
    RailsProject$ bundle exec bundle -v
    Bundler version 1.0.18
```

I tried all that `gem pristine --all --no-extensions` stuff from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949521/how-do-i-fix-rubygems-recent-deprecation-warning/5993502#5993502) - with and without `bundle exec`

Every gem is up-to-date.

Does anybody have an idea how to solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to install ZenTest 4.6.2.
if you use rails 3.1,you will find that 
autotest-rails (4.1.1) dependency on ZenTest (= 4.5.0).
just modified the Gemfile.lock, search the ZenTest, change it to use 4.6.2, and change the

```
autotest (4.4.6)
  ZenTest (= 4.5.0)
```

to

```
autotest (4.4.6)
  ZenTest (= 4.6.2)
```

then, run

```
bundle install
```

That's all.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not using the latest version of ZenTest. You're using 4.5.0 and the latest is 4.6.2.

Try running

```
gem update ZenTest
gem update autotest
```

and you might need to update your **Gemfile** in your rails app and run `bundle install` to lock the gemfile to the latest versions of the gems.

Comment: `bundle exec gem update ZenTest` updated ZenTest somehow to 4.6.2, but although I did a `bundle install` rake still seems to use 4.5 (warnings remain).Do I have to specify ZenTest in my Gemfile?

Comment: `$ bundle exec gem list ZenTest` produces: `*** LOCAL GEMS ***

ZenTest (4.5.0)`

Comment: Aah, got the reason for the problem. After specifying Zentest 4.6.2 in the Gemfile, I got that: `autotest-rails depends on
      ZenTest (= 4.5)`