# 'rails new depot' gets me a bunch of errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm

I messed up with rvm and ruby version.
Now it stopped giving me a new rails app with 'rails new newapp'
I tried to update ruby version to 1.9.2 with rvm.
Any idea?

$ rails new depot
NOTE:`Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.`

```
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Users/Hw/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/specifications/rake-0.8.7.gemspec:10.
/Users/Hwa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find treetop (~> 1.4.8) amongst [abstract-1.0.0, actionmailer-3.0.7, actionpack-3.0.7, activeadmin-0.2.1, activemodel-3.0.7, activerecord-3.0.7, activeresource-3.0.7, activesupport-3.0.7, arel-2.0.9, bcrypt-ruby-2.1.4, builder-2.1.2, bundler-1.0.13, devise-1.3.4, erubis-2.6.6, formtastic-1.2.3, haml-3.1.1, has_scope-0.5.0, highline-1.6.1, i18n-0.5.0, inherited_resources-1.2.2, inherited_views-0.0.2, jruby-0.0.1, mail-2.3.0, mail-2.2.19, meta_search-1.0.5, mime-types-1.16, oauth-0.4.4, orm_adapter-0.0.5, polyglot-0.3.1, rack-1.2.2, rack-mount-0.6.14, rack-test-0.5.7, rails-3.0.7, railties-3.0.7, rake-0.8.7, responders-0.6.4, rvm-1.6.9, thor-0.14.6, twurl-0.6.3, tzinfo-0.3.27, vmail-1.6.5, warden-1.0.4, will_paginate-3.0.pre2] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/Hwa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:748:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    from /Users/Hwa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:745:in `each'
    from /Users/Hwa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:745:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /Users/Hwa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:730:in `activate'
    from /Users/Hwa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:751:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    from /Users/Hwa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:745:in `each'
    from /Users/Hwa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:745:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /Users/Hwa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:730:in `activate'
    from /Users/Hwa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:751:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    from /Users/Hwa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:745:in `each'
    from /Users/Hwa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:745:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /Users/Hwa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:730:in `activate'
    from /Users/Hwa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1183:in `gem'
    from /Users/Hwa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/rails:18:in `<main>'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949521/how-do-i-fix-rubygems-recent-deprecation-warning

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909108/how-to-avoid-deprecation-messages-from-rubygems

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985363/how-to-get-rid-of-this-single-deprecation-message

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the treetop gem. The deprecation warnings are just that. The relevant line here is:

```
/Users/Hwa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find treetop (~> 1.4.8) amongst [abstract-1.0.0, actionmailer-3.0.7, actionpack-3.0.7, activeadmin-0.2.1, activemodel-3.0.7, activerecord-3.0.7, activeresource-3.0.7, activesupport-3.0.7, arel-2.0.9, bcrypt-ruby-2.1.4, builder-2.1.2, bundler-1.0.13, devise-1.3.4, erubis-2.6.6, formtastic-1.2.3, haml-3.1.1, has_scope-0.5.0, highline-1.6.1, i18n-0.5.0, inherited_resources-1.2.2, inherited_views-0.0.2, jruby-0.0.1, mail-2.3.0, mail-2.2.19, meta_search-1.0.5, mime-types-1.16, oauth-0.4.4, orm_adapter-0.0.5, polyglot-0.3.1, rack-1.2.2, rack-mount-0.6.14, rack-test-0.5.7, rails-3.0.7, railties-3.0.7, rake-0.8.7, responders-0.6.4, rvm-1.6.9, thor-0.14.6, twurl-0.6.3, tzinfo-0.3.27, vmail-1.6.5, warden-1.0.4, will_paginate-3.0.pre2] (Gem::LoadError)
```